# Spooky ISP settings

Tags: network, router, internet, tr-069

I recently switched to some local internet provider who is relatively a fresh boy in town. It is a wireless setup, with wifi antenna attached to a router in home. This is a fritzbox kid.

I observed remote access is configured for it. There were 2 users , one named "ftpuser" and another "TR069-" followed by some random string I don't recall. I removed this user but I'm not sure if is a big deal.

The router reported TR-069 service enabled but the port used is different than the one for internet remote access from which those two users benefited. Anyone has any idea of what use was the user I removed? Also just in case can I recover the credentials somehow? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## What is TR-069

> TR-069 is the industry standard CPE WAN Management Protocol defined by the Broadband Forum and has more than 700 million subscribers worldwide. It is intended for communication between a CPE and Auto-Configuration Server (ACS). The CPE WAN Management Protocol defines a mechanism that encompasses secure auto -configuration of a CPE, and also incorporates other CPE management functions into a common framework.[Source](http://www.broadband-forum.org/projects/connected-user/tr-069-and-its-evolution)

TR-069 is a way for ISPs to manage the devices they provide, and to allow them to both update the devices and provide support

## What benefit does TR-069 provide

Having the ability to talk to the CPE can really help in support situations, as technicians can see what is going on, and if the call center is sufficiently well equiped the call center staff can be directed more quickly toward issues.

## What are the risks of TR-069

If you have no use of the support features (and your ISP does not require TR-069 in order to get support if you have line issues), then you may be better off temporarily disabling it. There have been exploits against TR-069 implementations in the past:

- [TR-069 NewNTPServer Exploits: What we know so far](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/TR069+NewNTPServer+Exploits+What+we+know+so+far/21763/)